# Drupal commerce add to cart confirmation not showing

Tags: drupal, message, confirmation, commerce

I am having a problem because there is not a confirmation message after clicking add to cart button.I have checked in rules and the message is enabled.
I also installed the module add to cart confirmation but also nothing shows up.
I am very confused because it is important for a store to have this message.
I am using Drupal 7.53
Please help!

Thanks in advance,

Antonis

Comment: We can't debug your code if you don't show it to us.

Comment: sorry for asking, but how can i do this?

Comment: You could setup a demo link to review your problem.

Answer (score 0):

it was a theme issue.
i was using my own bootstrap subtheme but then i switched to bootstrap barrio
and everything was fine.
Maybe i had done something wrong in page.tpl.php